# JVM don't call gc, why G1 Old Gen memory decreased?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

These days, I found my service's memory rises a little every day, like this pic:
[image]

then, I opened JVM monitor page, and found that no FULL GC occured in these days:
[image]

so, my question: Why JVM don't call FULL GC the last 5 days,
and why G1 Old Gen memory growth and last decreased?

thands a lot.

btw: my jar execute command was:
java -server -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=40.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=10.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=85.0 -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dserver.port=80 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/init/configure/app/dumps -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/init/configure/app/s3-client -javaagent:/init/configure/app/jmx_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=9009:/init/configure/app/config.yaml -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps -jar /opt/main.jar

Comment: A significant portion of the 2.18GiB of the first picture are not connected to the heap at all. The heap’s maximum of committed memory is 1147MiB, according to the second picture. A collection of the young generation can promote objects to the old generation, so a growth of the old generation is not surprising. Large objects, e.g. arrays, may even get allocated directly in the old gen. There’s obviously no pressure to perform a Full GC with only 495MiB of 2.38GiB of the old gen in use at max. Still, a minor GC *does* collect parts of the Old Gen, so decreasing isn’t surprising either.

Comment: @Holger thanks. So how to prevent the system memory from rising every day? now I restart my service Every week to avoid memory alarm.

Comment: Configure a smaller maximum heap.